# rails 4 paperclip not uploading multiple images but just one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am using paperclip in my rails app

my form is

```
<%= form_for @portfolio_photo, :url => portfolio_photo_uplaod_individual_profile_path(:profile_id => current_individual.profile.id), :method => :POST, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :profile_id, :value => current_individual.profile.id %>
  <%= file_field_tag :portfolio_photo, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and controller action is

```
def portfolio_photo_uplaod
  @portfolio_photo = IndividualPhoto.create(portfolio_photo_params)
  if @portfolio_photo.save
    redirect_to individual_profile_path(current_individual)
  end
end
```

and the strong parameters are

```
def portfolio_photo_params
  params.permit(:portfolio_photo, :profile_id)
end
```

**individual_photo.rb**

```
class IndividualPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  has_attached_file :portfolio_photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :portfolio_photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
has_many :individual_photos
```

i am able to save when i upload a single image but i am not able to save multiple images instead only one image is saving in the database when i upload multiple images 
Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for your current system:

In your form:

```
<%= form_for @portfolio_photo, :url => portfolio_photo_uplaod_individual_profile_path(:profile_id => current_individual.profile.id), :method => :POST, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :profile_id, :value => current_individual.profile.id %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'portfolio_photos[]', multiple: true %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
def portfolio_photo_uplaod
  portfolio_photo_params[:portfolio_photos].each do |photo|
    IndividualPhoto.create(portfolio_photo: photo, profile_id: portfolio_photo_params[:profile_id])
  end
  redirect_to individual_profile_path(current_individual)
end
```

and the strong parameters:

```
def portfolio_photo_params
  params.permit(:profile_id, :portfolio_photos => [])
end
```

---

With your current design, above solution should work but it's not the best approach yet, you have some better ways to achieve this e.g. using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to update Profile's photos through Profile Controller.